# Does the Weblogic.Messaging.dll .NET client support T3S?

Tags: .net, jms, weblogic12c

I am working with the Weblogic.Messaging.dll .NET client to communicate with a JMS server running on a Weblogic 12c instance. I am trying to connect to this JMS server using the secure "T3S" protocol, but I am having problems doing so. I am starting to suspect that the .NET client does not support T3S, only T3, but I haven't found any official documentation which confirms that hypothesis.

Does anyone know if Weblogic.Messaging.dll supports T3S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I have come to the conclusion that the Weblogic JMS .NET client only supports T3, not T3S.

Here's the documentation which led me to this conclusion:

I found this statement in the old BEA Weblogic documentation from 2007:

> SSL is not supported for the JMS .NET client in this release. Therefore, it is important that you secure the networking services that the operating system provides, as well as any networking connections. For more information, see “Securing Network Connections” in Securing a Production Environment.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/essex/TechPreview/pdf/jms_dotnet.pdf

There's also this table on a more recent Oracle documentation page. Note that SSL is conspicuously absent from the JMS .NET Client entry:

[image]

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55108_01/doc.1213/e56762/products2.htm

**Update:** I submitted a Support Request to Oracle asking if they support T3S. They confirmed that the .NET JMS client does not support SSL.